# iOS Objective-c How to close model window

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am sure this is a piece of cake for you, but for a newbie like me, I have no clue.
I created a iOS project with a storyboard with the following item:

A)Navigation controller
B)Table View Controller
C)Table View Controller
D)Demo.h and Demo.m

-I have seques connect (A) to (B) via Push, and connect (B) to (C) via Modal

-I have a button on (C) called "Close", what I want is when I click on Close button, (C) will be closed itself and turns control back to (B).

This is what I have so far on the Demo.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interfaces Demo: UITableViewController
//I am not sure if I should inherit this base class or not
-(IBAction) CloseClick;
@end
```

-in the Demo.m I have a method to handle click like this:

```
#import "Demo.h"
@implementation Demo  
-(IBAction) CloseClick{
//TODO:
}
@end
```

Then I wired the "Close" button on (C) to CloseClick method in Demo.h, Now I don't know how to modify this class so that it closes (C) when button is clicked. I am using XCode 5

-Thanks a lot in advance!
-Newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(IBAction) CloseClick{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

}
```

or, if you're on iOS 5 and above, use

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

or if you want to return to previous view on navigation stack

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```